# ¿Cómo mostrar x cantidad de elementos al dar clic? PHP JQuery MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

Tengo una "lista" de elementos que se muestran de forma dinámica desde la base de datos con php:

```
<div id='1' class="entradaDesp2">
  <?php
try {
  require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
  $blog = "blog";
  $prog = "programada";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id_entrada,titulo,descripcion,estado FROM entradas WHERE tipo_entrada=? AND estado!=? ORDER BY id_entrada ASC LIMIT 6');
  $stmt->bind_param('ss',$blog,$prog);
  $stmt->execute();
  $elementos = $stmt->get_result();
  while ($ele = $elementos->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($ele as $blogBajo) { ?>
```

Los muestro dentro de este `section`:

```
      <section class="articulosBajos clearfix relativo" id="artIndex">
        <article class="articulo">
          <img src="../img/imagen.jpg" alt="">
          <h2><?php echo $blogBajo['titulo'] ?></h2>
          <p class="alto"><?php echo $blogBajo['descripcion'] ?>...</p>
        </article>
      </section>
      <!--Final articulo-->
    <?php
    }
  } $stmt->close();
} catch (exception $e) {
  $error = $e->getMessage();
} ?>
<!--Final articulo-->
</div>
```

De este modo se crean x cantidad de `section` como se encuentren en la base de datos. Yo necesito que se vean solo 6 o x cantidad, dado que si hay 30 `article` no se vean todos a la vez, sino que se vean los primeros 6 y cuando se de clic a un botón (como estos que van a la página siguiente) se muestren los siguientes 6 y así hasta los últimos elementos. Como las lista del historial de transferencias bancarias, por ejemplo, que se muestran los primeros 50 elementos y al final tiene unos botones que te permiten avanzar o retroceder entre las pestañas que muestran dichos elementos.

No tengo ni la más mínima idea de cómo empezar con eso... todo lo de arriba funciona correctamente, y por el momento solo tomo los primeros 6 elementos desde la base de datos, no sé si se deban traer todos y con JQuery mostrar x cantidad o haya una forma de traer los 6 primeros y luego volver a seleccionar de la base de datos los 6 siguientes.

Espero me puedan ayudar. Comenten si necesitan mayor información.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero: esto se resuelve a travez de MySQL y ajax, en MySQL esta el comando Limit el cual muchos las usan solo con el primer parámetro el cual limita la cantidad de registros a traer ej:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY columna LIMIT 6;
```

Pero si lo usamos con 2 parámetros el primero sera el registro de inicio($start) y el segundo la cantidad de registros a devolver ($limit)

```
SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY columna LIMIT $start, $limit;
```

Una vez explicado este punto es necesario abocarnos a PHP, debemos crear un script que sea capaz de leer las variables que serán Posteadas a través de ajax.

El primer paso es setear un valor $page el cual sera la plana actual inicial y la que devolverá los valores cuando se cargue el php en un principio:

```
 <?php if(!isset($_GET['page'])) $page=1;
 else $page = $_GET['page'];
```

El segundo paso será, setear la cantidad de registros a devolver si quieres que el usuario elija cuantos registros desea ver, si deseas este valor fijo, bastara con que dejes el campo input como solo lectura o mostrarlo como un label en la pagina que hará la carga:

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['rows'])) $limit=6;
else $limit = $_GET['rows'];
```

El cual en caso de no recibir ningún valor se le asignara un valor 6; 
el siguiente paso sera obtener la cantidad de registros que tiene la tabla ya que este valor sera necesario para calcular la cantidad de planas que deberán retornarse, mediante una consulta obtenemos el valor y se lo pasamos a una variable $count ej:

```
<?php if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT COUNT(idtabla) AS count FROM tabla")) {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
     $count = $row[0];
      };
```

luego mediante un simple calculo en php obtenemos los valores para el total de planas

```
<?php if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) {
          $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
} else {
          $total_pages = 0;
}
```

Una vez que tenemos todos estos parámetros podremos hacer la consulta en la base de datos la cual nos traerá solo los registros requeridos.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY campo LIMIT $start , $limit";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,  $query ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error());
```

Luego de eso debes adaptarlo a como deseas que se muestre, json es la mejor alternativa, pero también lo puedes hacer con un echo

El ultimo paso es crear un ajax que lea un campo input de tu pagina el cual será el indicador de planas este campo también lo puedes dejar como solo lectura y que mediante este valor haga la carga del script php, recuerda que deberás sumar 1 al valor que estas leyendo, ademas debes poner 2 botones o links por medio de los cuales avanzar o retroceder entre las planas, la creación del ajax es medianamente sencilla, ese paso te lo dejo por que deberás adaptar tu código al llamado mediante ajax, te adjunto el link de JQgrid en el cual la muestra de registros es parte básica de su interfaz. espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: Gracias por la información. Al final, ¿Qué haces con la variable `$start`? supongo que con eso organizas que cuando cambie la plana el `$start` cambia su valor... ¿podrías ejemplificar cómo?

Comment: exacto, eso es lo que hace para el caso tuyo el $start iría de 6 en 6 y eso es lo que tienes que hacer con ajax puedes hacer las planas fijas y leer un label de la pagina para que de el $start como ya sabes cuantas planas se van a mostrar no sería difícil mostrar un listado de las planas y si por ejemplo muestra la tercera plana tan solo debes multiplicar por 3 (6x3=18) entonces el $start comienza en 18.