# Buscar datos cuando pulsas en la flecha del grid (jqgrid)

Tags: jquery, angular, jqgrid

tengo un consulta que me devuelve 5 registro, aunque haya más, que me busca a partir de nº peticion.
la primera consulta me lo busca desde la 0, pero la segunda ya es a partir del último registro.

Ejemplo primera llamada me devuelve esto:

0001

0002

0003

0005

0008

La segunda sería a partir de 0008.

Claro esto habría que hacerlo mientras que hay resultados. Y claro y hacerlo con un while() en el java que es como lo tengo y que lo haga mientras no tengo más resultados funciona pero pensandolo, si hubiera por ejemplo 10.000 registros eso tardaría mucho o sería poco efectivo(corregidme si me equivoco) y había pensado hacer la primera consulta y que luego cuando pinches en en la flecha que me haga la segunda consulta.

¿Eso es posible? he estado mirando por todos los lados y no he visto algo que me pueda ayudar.

muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa la demora en responder, vengo recién llegando a la etiqueta jqgrid, no sabía que existía en stackoverflow, bueno para tu problema necesitas usar MySQL limit suponiendo que usas MySQL, pero en todo caso creo que en los demás motores debe haber algo similar, en Mysql si usas limit n, te devuelve n registros, pero si usas limit s, n , devuelve n registros comenzando desde la variable s. ej:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE 1 LIMIT 1, 100
```

Esto te retornará 100 registros de clientes comenzando en el primer registro , estos valores se pasan a variables y de esta manera es fácil agregarlos mediante php que es el lenguaje en el cual programo, para el caso de java debe ser análogo , en todo caso en los ejemplos de jqgrid están bien documentados los temas de paginación que es lo que finalmente necesitas.
te dejo un link con unos ejemplos.

[cómo mostrar x cantidad de elementos al dar clic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344850/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-x-cantidad-de-elementos-al-dar-clic-php-jquery-mysql/345936#345936)