# Insertar paginación en CRUD PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una consulta, estoy realizando un **CRUD** con **paginación**. Tengo mi archivo principal (**index.php**) y aparte tengo otro archivo el cual contiene el código de paginación (**paginacion.php**). Mi idea es realizando en dos archivos. El número de registros me los muestra perfecto, pero al momento de visualizar por **index.php** las paginas y a su vez ir cambiando de paginas (lo principal de este ejercicio) no me visualiza nada en pantalla. Comprobé que no aplica el bucle for. Mi pregunta es, ¿ cómo puedo llamar al bucle for dentro del **index.php**? o de lo contrario que el bucle for, este en la pagina **paginacion.php**, pero que se cumpla el objetivo en la pagina **index.php**. Muchas gracias.

//index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CRUD</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hoja.css">

 
</head>

<body>

<?php

 include ("conexion.php");

 include ("paginacion.php");


  $registros=$base->query("select * from inventario_productos limit $empezar_desde, $tamano_paginas")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 

?>


<h1>LO_QUIERO_NOW<span class="subtitulo">Inventario</span></h1>
<form action="insertar_datos.php" method="post">
  <table width="50%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr >
      <td class="primera_fila">Id</td>
      <td class="primera_fila">Produtos</td>
      <td class="primera_fila">Descripción</td>
      <td class="primera_fila">Valor</td>
      <td class="primera_fila">Color</td>
      <td class="primera_fila">Estado</td>
      <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr> 
   
    <?php

    foreach ($registros as $item) :?>
        
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $item->id ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $item->productos ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $item->descripcion ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $item->valor ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $item->color ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $item->estado ?></td>
 
      <td class="bot"><a href="borrar.php? id=<?php echo $item->id ?>"><input type='button' name='del' id='del' value='Borrar'></a></td>

      <td class='bot'><a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $item->id ?> & prod=<?php echo $item->productos ?> & des=<?php echo $item->descripcion ?> & val=<?php echo $item->valor?> & col=<?php echo  $item->color ?> & est=<?php echo $item->estado ?>"><input type='button' name='up' id='up' value='Actualizar'></a></td>
    </tr>     

    <?php

      endforeach;

    ?>  




    <tr>
    <td></td>
      
      <td><input type='text' name='Pro' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='Desc' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='Val' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='Col' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='Est' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
      <td class='bot'><input type='submit' name='cr' id='cr' value='Insertar'></td></tr>
      <tr><td><?php


      ///______________PAGINACION__________________________________________- 


        include ("paginacion.php");

        $total_paginas=ceil($num_filas/$tamano_paginas);

        echo "hola";


                for ($i=1; $i<=$total_paginas; $i++){

                  echo "<a href='?pagina=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a>";



                }

        ?></td></tr>
        
  </table>
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

//paginacion.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

    include ("conexion.php");


    try{


    if (isset($_GET["pagina"])){

        if ($_GET["pagina"]==1){

            header ("location:index.php");

        } else {

            $pagina=$_GET["pagina"];
        }

    } //FIN ISSET;

    else {

        $pagina=1;
    }


        $tamano_paginas=3;

        $empezar_desde=($pagina-1)*$tamano_paginas;

        $sql_total="select * from inventario_productos";

        $resultado=$base->prepare($sql_total);

        $num_filas=$resultado->rowCount();

        $total_paginas=ceil($num_filas/$tamano_paginas);


    } //FIN TRY

    catch (Exeption $e){

        echo " Error en la línea: " . $e->getLine();

    }

        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_paginas; $i++){


    echo "<a href='?pagina=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
    
  }



    ?>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tal vez te pueda servir este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344850/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-x-cantidad-de-elementos-al-dar-clic-php-jquery-mysql/345936#345936)

Answer (score 0):

No puedes utilizar un `header()` en medio una página web:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Deberías reorganizar un poco el código para que hagas el `include()` de fragmentos de código, no de páginas completas. Es más, podrías tener todo tu código en el `index.php` y utilizar, por ejemplo, funciones para reutilizar ese código.

No hay inconveniente en interactuar un poco más y continuar dándole forma. Ánimo, que casi lo tienes.

Comment: si amigo, pensé en dejar todo mi código en una pagina, pero quería reutilizar mi código a futuro y a su vez más fácil de leer. Le daré una vuelta más. Gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es reutilizar código, créate una clase con métodos que te quedará mucho mejor documentada que ficheritos sueltos... Para empezar tampoco te líes, focalízate en que funcione. Con la práctica, ya programarás bonito, date tiempo... ¡Anda que no cambiarás veces de estilo! :)