# Paginacion con PHP

Tags: php, paginacion

Tengo una tabla con la siguiente consulta a la DB:

```
Q_Clientes   = mysqli_query($MySQLi,"SELECT * FROM Clientes ")or die(mysqli_error($MySQLi)."<br>Error en la línea: ".__LINE__);
$resultCliente= mysqli_num_rows($Q_Clientes);
$porPagina    = 10;
$paginas      = ceil($resultCliente/$porPagina);
$iniciar      = ($_GET['pagina']-1)*$porPagina;
$Q_Clientes_  = mysqli_query($MySQLi,"SELECT * FROM Clientes ORDER BY idCliente ASC LIMIT $iniciar,$porPagina ");
```

Y en la paginación, el siguiente código:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
    <li class="page-item <?= $_GET['pagina']<=1?'disabled':'' ?>">
      <a class="page-link" href="?root=<?=$_GET['root'] ?>&pagina=<?=$_GET['pagina']-1 ?>" tabindex="-1">Anterior</a>
     </li><?php
     for ($i=0; $i < $paginas ; $i++) { ?>
      <li class="page-item <?= $_GET['pagina']==$i+1 ? 'active': '' ?>">
       <a class="page-link" href="?root=<?=$_GET['root'] ?>&pagina=<?=$i+1 ?>"><?=$i+1 ?></a>
      </li><?php 
     } ?>
     <li class="page-item <?= $_GET['pagina']>=$porPagina ?'disabled':'' ?>">
      <a class="page-link" href="?root=<?=$_GET['root'] ?>&pagina=<?=$_GET['pagina']+1 ?>">Siguiente</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que la pregunta sería baste lógica, pero:

Cómo hago que me muestre "x" cantidad determinada y conforme avance a la siguiente o anterior página, aumente o disminuya.

Perdón, no se si me di a explicar, soy nuevo en esto.
de ante mano, muchas gracias!!

---

Encontré esos detalles, cómo les doy solución?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mira como quedó el código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como veras, le tuve que sumar 1 a la última página, ya que no me mostraba la última (valga la redundancia)
cómo lo soluciono?
Puedo agregar un botón de "Primero" y "último"?

Comment: Tal vez esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344850/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-x-cantidad-de-elementos-al-dar-clic-php-jquery-mysql/345936#345936) te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría limitar ese for para que desde la página actual te de por ejemplo las cuatro siguiente:

```
    $pagesToShow = 4;

    $currentPage = $_GET['pagina']>;

    $endPage = $currentPage + $pageToShow;

    if ($endPage > $paginas){
        $endPage = $paginas;
    }


    for ($i = $currentPage; $i < $endPage; $i++){
    // Acá imprimes los enlaces
    }
```

Espero que esto te ayude.

Saludos

Comment: Excelente ayuda, gracias. aun que me costó un poco acomodarlo a mi código pero ya lo hice. Lo único que, encontré estos detalles:
1) que en las últimas páginas se va reduciendo de 5 a 4, 3, 2, 1 hasta la última página, solo muestra esa misma página.
Lastima que no puedo mostrarte con imagenes para darme a entender mejor.
pero muchas gracias.

Comment: Es correcto, para hacerlo aún mejor podrías por ejemplo cuando te des cuenta que estás llegando al final, mostrar las páginas anteriores, pero imagino que ya lo harás bien.